# Is it appropriate to have view controllers that have multiple views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, view, controller

I have a quick question in regards to my app that I am developing for school. In my app we have 5 unique games that the user can play. However, each game has 2 modes, normal and hard. What is the best way about going to do this. Currently I have my first game as two separate view controllers and are called based on the difficulty that is wanted(one called normal_cstars and hard_cstars). I am wondering if this is efficient because each view controller has a .h, .m, and a .xib. Is it possible to have a view controller that has two separate views and how would you go about accomplishing this.

Thanks,

Ryan Wong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course.  You can pick which one of the two views you display inside your viewcontrollers.  Just send self.view in the view controller to be the view you'd like to use.

One way to architect this is to have two separate view classes that share the same controls.  The controls are all handled by the view controller while the views each draw their own layout.

And don't be worried about sharing subviews among the two main views -- or you can keep your two view controllers, and just have shared classes that make up the views and controls of each view controller's presentation.  Just because you have two view controllers doesn't mean you have to have redundancy code.  Split things out into separate classes, from your animated views to your controls.

There are a lot of other possibilities.  Look at some of Apple's samples to see how multiple view controllers are used.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really think that you need two separate views?  (I am not sure about your game though)

Since game modes are Model specific, a model with behaviour "Normal" or "Hard" will actually render the game in a view.

If near future, if you want to implement a mode "Easy" then you end up with another view controller and might encounter code redundancy.

Solution I would think:

- Create a [inheritance over composition pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) for your model objects.
- A view controller will be much more generic and tells view to render based on the mode
- Now the base class of the model will implement generic methods and since the model has mode as composition, the view will render the game objects based on it.

Advantages? - well we have not violated the Open-Closed Principle.

And again there are various design patterns out there to achieve this. Its up to you to decide which suits the best for the requirements.